# Type Casting for generating Cron Expression

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger

I am trying to generate cron expressions using java code and I'm having some hard time on type casting to generate the cron expression.

So my question is can we type cast SimpleScheduleBuilder to CronTrigger for generating Cron Expression ?

```
SimpleScheduleBuilder ssb = 
SimpleScheduleBuilder.repeatHourlyForever(date.getHours());
CronTrigger ct = (CronTrigger) newTrigger().withSchedule(ssb).build();
```

When I try to run this piece of code I'm getting

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.quartz.impl.triggers.SimpleTriggerImpl cannot be cast to org.quartz.CronTrigger
```

So can you let me the way to type cast SimpleScheduleBuilder to CronTrigger

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the applicable code and the error you're getting?

Comment: @cody can you find it more relevant now !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you cannot logically mix `SimpleScheduleBuilder` and `CronTrigger`. `SimpleScheduleBuilder` is for use with `SimpleTrigger`, `CronScheduleBuilder` is for use with `CronTrigger`.

Besides the way in which you define the schedules, there is really no difference between the two trigger types, in terms of best practices or performance. So I suggest you just use `SimpleTrigger` if the simpler schedule definition is suitable to your needs.

The tutorials on [SimpleTrigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-05.html) and [CronTrigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06.html) go into these differences in great detail.